# How can i get multiple radio button value from table in jquery into another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I want to make checkbox and get the selected table row into another table on click

This is the table to click the the checkbox:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered maintable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <td>Pilih</td>
            <td>Nama Obat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>lalal</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="transfer" class="transterrows">
```

This is the main table, table to show selected row that have been checklist:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered secondtable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Nama Obat</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the jquery that I tried but failed:

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "transterrows", function () {
        var getselectedvalue = $(".maintable input:checked").parents("tr").clone().appendTo($(".secondtable tbody").add(getselectedvalue));
    })
})
```

Comment: Please show any of your working :) (`HTML`, `JS`, `JQuery`, etc)

Comment: . You don't get tutorials here. You have to make some code trials. Then post question on technical issues.

Comment: @EGC i have update my question please check again

Comment: It looks like your missing the '.' for "transterrows" inside the click function

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function () {
      $(document).on("click", ".transterrows", function () {
          var getselectedvalue = $(".maintable input:checked").parents("tr").clone().appendTo($(".secondtable tbody").add(getselectedvalue));
      })
  })
```

It seems to work if you add the '.' in you click function to select the class transterrows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   $(function () {
          $(".transterrows").on("click", function () {
              var getselectedvalue = $(".maintable input:checked").parents("tr").clone();
              $(".secondtable tbody").append(getselectedvalue);
          })
      })
```